# Network Neighbours

Tags: telnet

I am new to networking. I just basically want to know whether we can actually get to know the no of persons logged onto our network. Since i am in a university we have the same proxy address and the IP is also same. So is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this question should be asked on superuser.com.

It depends a bit on your network. If your internal IP addresses are dynamically allocated, your administrator will be able to see how many of them have been requested. He may also monitor the traffic, and see from his statistics how many addresses have actually been seen as active. If your network uses authentication, he may monitor the valid logins over time.

Which of these you define as 'people on your network' is a bit up to you. Real people don't have that kind of interface.

Comment: sorry for posting wrong things and thanks for the links